# Position div below div with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/6H4RA/1/

How would I put the red rectangle direcetly below the green rectangle (which is positioned absolutely), with the knowledge that the height of the green rectangle can vary?

HTML:

```
<div class="absolute"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.absolute {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use position Absolute ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use `position: absolute` but you may be interested on `margin: auto`  - http://jsfiddle.net/6H4RA/3/

Comment: @JunM I'm an idiot. Completely forgot about margin: auto. Thanks. :P

Comment: Was that the only reason you were using absolute? Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @MarkM Yes, that solved the problem. :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to ask. I took out the positioning and the margin from the .absolute div then added positioning to the .footer div

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dominex/6H4RA/7/#&togetherjs=Ie8lAT2IiG)

```
.absolute {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: green;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
}
```